# startService restart my service if currently running, the Android docs say the opposite

Tags: android, service

in my service, I download a lot of stuff from the internet and would like to do this every x hours (choice in Preferences)

The current implementation I have written in this code in the main Activity:

```
    Intent svc = new Intent(this, AlarmService.class);

    if (startService(svc)!=null) {
        Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Service already running");
    } else {
        Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Service Started");
    }
```

Because, according to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29)

> Request that a given application service be started. The Intent can
>   either contain the complete class name of a specific service
>   implementation to start, or an abstract definition through the action
>   and other fields of the kind of service to start. If this service is
>   not already running, it will be instantiated and started (creating a
>   process for it if needed); **if it is running then it remains running**.

That last sentence that I highlited let me hope that I could write all my heavy code in the onCreate of the service and it will be untouched, but unfortunately, everytime the user starts the app, the service starts again and make a huge download, draining the battery.

The indication if the service is running or not is correct:

> Returns If the service is being started or is already running, the
>   ComponentName of the actual service that was started is returned; else
>   if the service does not exist null is returned.

So, my question, How can I let the service untouched if already started, and start it if not yet started?

Thanks

EDIT:

The service in never stopped:

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {

    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("**", "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
        // DO NOTHING FOR TESTING alarm.SetAlarm(this);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in my service, I download a lot of stuff from the internet and would like to do this every x hours (choice in Preferences)

Hopefully you are doing this with an `IntentService` (possibly [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful)) and `AlarmManager`.

> That last sentence that I highlited let me hope that I could write all my heavy code in the onCreate of the service and it will be untouched, but unfortunately, everytime the user starts the app, the service starts again and make a huge download, draining the battery.

That is because either the service had been stopped (via `stopService()` or `stopSelf()`), or because your app's process was terminated.

> How can I let the service untouched if already started, and start it if not yet started?

Call `startService()`, as the documentation indicates.

But if you are really trying "to do this every x hours", the user will really appreciate it if your service does *not* waste RAM trying to stick around during that time. Hence, the user or the OS may well get rid of your process during the "x hours". If you do not want to do the "huge download" every "x hours", then you need to save that information locally to some sort of file.

Comment: Using an IntentService was a big problem because the Intent is destroyed after having done its stuff "stops itself when it runs out of work." so, startService laways returns null => http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: When I meant huge download , I exagerated a lot, That is just huge text files that hard hard to parse. (weather + public transportation +placesthat REALLY need to be downloaded every X hour depending on user location and changes

Comment: @Waza_Be: That was not the point behind my last paragraph, or my asking you to re-read it. Let me reproduce the key sentences here: But if you are really trying "to do this every x hours", the user will really appreciate it if your service does not waste RAM trying to stick around during that time. Hence, the user or the OS may well get rid of your process during the "x hours".

Comment: If he wants to get rid of it, well, I won't download weather, and his public transportations timetables. Because he stopped it, the app won't download, that's the purpose, no? There is a preference in the settings to set the X, so he hazs a full controlm over the app

Comment: @Waza_Be: Please provide any technical justification for keeping your service in memory constantly.

Comment: The start of my service is set in the onCreate of my mainACtivity. Each time I start the MainActivity, the service is restarted (and download restart), the only way I have found to avoid this is to make the service permanent and do nothing between 2 downloads (that will add stuff in SQL), so the memory impact is non existant. I am open to a better way to achieve this.